# I can not use speech_recognition

Tags: python-3.x

Hello I have copied code below from website about python for convert my voice to text but it has a bug that i can't understand or fix. Can you guy teach me some reason.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:                
r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
while True:
 print("said")
 audio = r.listen(source)
 try:
  print("You said " + r.recognize_google(audio))  
 except LookupError:                           
  print("i do not understand audio")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnERY.jpg)

Comment: seems that audio might be empty? Have you seen if it prints out a value you were expecting?

Comment: @AxelPersinger  it prints "said".

Comment: I'm just guessing since I'm not familiar with the library, but looking at the stack trace, it says `if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: ...`, which means it's looking for a `dict` type with a key of `alternative` containing a list.

Comment: @AxelPersinger Do you think it might be happen from my hardware ?

Comment: Ah you misunderstood my earlier comment by the way, let's try that. Put `print(audio)` on a new line after `audio = r.listen(source)`. What does that print? And no, I doubt it's a hardware issue

Comment: @AxelPersinger it prints   <speech_recognition.AudioData object at 0x03C8B7B0>

Comment: Ah, found your issue :). Looking at the actual source of speech_recognition https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/speech_recognition/__init__.py#L857 says that if the speech is unintelligible (if it doesn't understand what you said) it will throw a `speech_recognition.UnknownValueError`. I found this by going to the official speech_recognition in GitHub looking at the __init__.py file (from your stack trace) and searching for the function. Hope this helps :)

Comment: @AxelPersinger  I really appreciate it , however, i still don't understand why it can not record my voice.

Comment: Make sure your microphone is working, you're speaking clearly into the microphone, etc. If you look at the function it also requires an API Key (but will default to a generic one), maybe try getting your own API Key, too?

Comment: @AxelPersinger How do i get one? sorry for this question lol

Comment: For the record, a lot of other people on this site will not help you this much, you'll have to do a little more research yourself. The answer is a few lines above the link I mentioned earlier.
"To obtain your own API key, simply following the steps on the `API Keys <http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys>`__ page at the Chromium Developers site. In the Google Developers Console, Google Speech Recognition is listed as "Speech API"."

Comment: @AxelPersinger Thank you for helping me. I own you big time.

Comment: @AxelPersinger finally, I found the solution, it just handle  UnknownValue exception. Thank you again for this help.

Answer (score 0):

use this code.It worked for me in pycharm

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("speak into mic")
    audio = r.listen(source,timeout=2)


try:
    print("Transcription:" + r.recognize_google(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Audio Unintelligible")

except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("cannot obtain results : {0}".format(e))
```

`